# Unable to parse soap 1.1 message wcf client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, axis, soap-client

Good day all, I am consuming soap 1.1 service built on Apache axis via WCF client. Issue is that both fault and normal response are not parsed by built in deserilizer of WCF and i am getting an exception related to XML parsing when calling a web operation via wcf client. When I inspect the message I got this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <V2Response xmlns="urn:ETS">
      <V2Return xsi:type="ns1:TResponse" xmlns:ns1="urn:ETS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <fulfilmentRef></fulfilmentRef>
        <paymentRef></paymentRef>
        <statusCode>2013</statusCode>
        <statusDescription>ePayments: Invalid client password specified in request.</statusDescription>
        <transactionId xsi:nil="true" />
        <transactionTimeStamp>2013-06-21T08:22:16.483Z</transactionTimeStamp>
      </V2Return>
    </V2Response>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The exception which I am getting is:

```
> The specified type was not recognized: name='TResponse', namespace='urn:ETS', at <V2Return xmlns='urn:ETS'>
```

I have a valid `TResponse` class in `Reference.cs`, please let me know if this can be handled by changing configurations, I was expecting WCF client to parse any soap message but it couldn't, I cannot change anything on server side, it is the 3rd party api.

Comment: does your service have a WSDL?

Comment: Yes I have the wsdl, I am adding service reference in my .Net project

Comment: Is V2Return inheriting from TResponse?

Comment: TResponse is an object with name V2Return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem by changing namespace manually in proxy class generated by svcutil.exe. "TResponse" class have some different namespace defined in proxy code, when i changed namespace to urn:ETS, soap response easily deserialized into class. Before that i have checked the response from SoapUI and validated soap response and everything was looking perfect, then i searched on SO and found  [This url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017700/invoking-a-java-axis-web-service-from-net-the-return-null-issue). After reading the exception again I realized that issue is in the namespace.

Below is change which i did:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.4927")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://axis.webservices.api.etransactions")]
    public partial class TResponse : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
        ........
```

I replaced "http://axis.webservices.api.etransactions"  with "urn:ETransactionsService" and it worked, :)!